# Most efficient way to compare multiple files in python

Tags: python

My problem is this. I have one file with 3000 lines and 8 columns(space delimited). The important thing is that the first column is a number ranging from 1 to 22. So in the principle of divide-n-conquer I splitted the original file in to 22 subfiles depending on the first column value.

And I have some result files. Which are 15 sources each containing 1 result file. But the result file is too big, so I applied divide-n-conquer once more to split each of the 15 results in to 22 subfiles.

the file structure is as follows:

```
Original_file                Studies
    split_1                      study1
                                     split_1, split_2, ...
    split_2                      study2
                                     split_1, split_2, ...
    split_3                      ...
    ...                          study15
                                     split_1, split_2, ...
    split_22
```

So by doing this, we pay a slight overhead in the beginning, but all of these split files will be deleted at the end. so it doesn't really matter.

I need my final output to be the original file with some values from the studies appended to it.

So, my take so far is this:

```
Algorithm:
    for i in range(1,22):
        for j in range(1,15)
            compare (split_i of original file) with the jth studys split_i
            if one value on a specific column matches:
                create a list with needed columns from both files, split row with ' '.join(list) and write the result in outfile.
```

Is there a better way to go around this problem? Because the study files range from 300MB to 1.5GB in size.

and here's my Python code so far:

```
folders = ['study1', 'study2', ..., 'study15']
with open("Effects_final.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for i in range(1, 23):
        chr = i
        small_file = "split_"+str(chr)+".txt"
        with open(small_file, 'r') as sf:
            for sline in sf: #small_files
                sf_parts = sline.split(' ')
                for f in folders:
                    file_to_compare_with = f + "split_" + str(chr) + ".txt"
                    with open(file_to_compare_with, 'r') as cf: #comparison files
                        for cline in cf:
                            cf_parts = cline.split(' ')
                            if cf_parts[0] == sf_parts[1]:
                               to_write = ' '.join(cf_parts+sf_parts) 
                               outfile.write(to_write)
```

But this code uses 4 loops which is an overkill, but you have to do it since you need to read the lines from the 2 files being compared at the same time. This is my concern...

Comment: Look into [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) which allows reading multiple streams at same time. Also it would be helpful to see data of these files to truly see what you are doing.

Comment: Is it taking to long to run, what's the exact problem here?

Comment: even if I use fileinput I still have to iterate through the files to compare. and they are not of the same size :/

Comment: @user2699 yes. the dataset i'm comparing against is 14GB in total.

Comment: So, are you talking hours to run, or minutes?

Comment: fix your code, lot's of stuff is not defined

Comment: @SebastianWozny please provide more details

Comment: @user2699 hours is too long. I would prefer minutes. we could multiprocess it. but is this efficient? And if yes? how...

Comment: what's dir_to_study and why do you loop `for f in folders` you never use f.
please provide actual input.

Comment: @SebastianWozny my bad, i'll fix it

Comment: make sure your code is reproducible, otherwise it should be closed.

Comment: @SebastianWozny it should be now.

Comment: I'ts not! what's `folders`

Comment: Ok, from your reply I'm guessing the code you've posted doesn't work.  So don't worry about speed yet.  The code might be ugly, but get working code first.  Once you the code runs, if you feel it runs too slow then look at pythons profiler.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? I guess these are 22 chromosome numbers. If you explain the actual file formats and bioinformatics issue, I'm sure there will be a fairly simple solution.

Comment: He/She reading from disk too often and he can't put everything in memory because it's too big. The reads will slow him/her down if he reads 1.5 gigs 23 times.

Comment: Also, if as you say the first file is 3000 lines and 8 columns, you can probably fit this entire file into memory with no need to split it, which will remove your outer loop and speed things up substantially.

Comment: @user2699 can you provide some code for your idea?

Comment: why does it have to be Python? There are definately solutions much more suited to such a task.

Comment: No. Also, I'd recommend looking at pandas, it's a library very well suited for data analysis and will simplify a lot of the file read/write code.  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one solution that seems to work in a good amount of time. The code is the following:

```
with open("output_file", 'w') as outfile:
    for i in range(1,23):
        dict1 = {}  # use a dictionary to map values from the inital file
        with open("split_i", 'r') as split:
            next(split) #skip the header
            line_list = line.split(delimiter)
            for line in split:
                dict1[line_list[whatever_key_u_use_as_id]] = line_list

            compare_dict = {}
            for f in folders:
                with open("each folder", 'r') as comp:
                    next(comp) #skip the header
                    for cline in comp:
                        cparts = cline.split('delimiter')
                        compare_dict[cparts[whatever_key_u_use_as_id]] = cparts
            for key in dict1:
                if key in compare_dict:
                    outfile.write("write your data")
outfile.close()
```

With this approach, I'm able to compute this dataset in ~10mins. Surely, there are ways for improvement. One idea, is to take the time and sort the datasets, that way search later on will be more quick, and we might save time!